# Set absolute dimension of object using Geometry Node

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

How can I set the absolute dimensions of an object using Geometry Nodes?

I could find a "Transform" node but not e.g. a "Dimensions" node.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This group will set the dimensions of your object, **before any object-level scaling,** which takes place after the mesh is modified:

[image]

If you wanted to offset (add or subtract) to/from the X,Y and /or Z dimensions of your object, the arithmetic is just slightly different:

[image]

The above group exposed the offsets in X,Y and Z to the interface, as a single vector...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 
Where do you set the actual dimension values in this setup?

Comment: Hi @Bernd ! In the modifier interface. (or in the node-group  interface, if you use this as a sub-group of another tree)

Comment: If I wanted to add a centimeter to my model's height, not set the height to a fixed value, can I do it using this graph?

Comment: Hi, @Richard .. see edit.

Comment: When I try to copy your second diagram 1) my `Offsets` is a vector type, not dimensions, - so I can set it to like 1.5 (times), not 1.5 cm.  2) My group output box says `Bounding Box` not `Geometry`

Comment: It is a vector, yes, you can make 3 separate offsets, 1 each for XYZ. so to add a centimetre to the height would be [0, 0, 0.01] .. will reconstruct for you....

Comment: @Richard See edit for  a shared file.

Comment: Isn't a vector of 0.01 10%? Not 1 cm or 1 m or 1 mile. I don't understand

Comment: The vector is just a way of clustering 3 values. In this case, the amount you want to _add_ to the dimensions, in X,Y,and Z, (in Blender Units). Check the Dimensions panel, while switching the modifier on and off.  You'll see.. (unless I'm going barking mad :) ) Sure, it achieves it by a non-uniform scale of the object. Do you mean you want some sort of extrusion, instead?

Comment: @Robin, if you have any time to look I'd appreciate it. - https://blend-exchange.com/b/o7SqljDx/.  I'm trying to use your offset and set nodes to expand a wall outwards, then squash it, to make a skirting board. But the offset seems to scale not set, and the setting seems to force unspecified axes to become 0.

Comment: Hi, Richard.. nowhere did you specify you wanted dimensions to be altered towards minimum Z... :) There is a more general problem though, with this approach to your file. All your walls are scaled in Object Mode. That transform is carried with the object. It takes place _after_ modifiers have manipulated the mesh (for which the Object is a 'vehicle' .. origin and coordinate system) so all the effects of any modifier are scaled, too. Also, the origins of your walls are halfway up one side. Any GN group made to compensate for this would have no generality, just solving a one-off problem.

Answer (score -1):

### Try the Bounding Box node.

It gives you 3 outputs:

- *Bounding Box*: a rectangular mesh representing your object's bounding box. (Essentially a cube sized to fit your mesh perfectly.)
- *Min*: The minimum X, Y, and Z positions of your mesh (how far it extends in the negative X, Y, and Z directions.)
- *Max*: The maximum X, Y, and Z positions for the mesh.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I see the Min, Max are outputs. Shouldn't there be inputs for those values to allow me set the Bounding Box size per parameter?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you only wanted to read the values :)

Comment: Use the answer above, it should do what you want.